# BizTalk: Host instance restart

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

As per my understanding if we restart a host instance, active message is going to be suspended. Could any one give me detail idea about in which scenario i could loose message.

I have orchestration with delay of 2 min. I tried to restart host instance and even stopped the instance. But my message is still in dehydrated stage.

Could any one let me different scenario with state of message?

Along with in which scenario I'm going to loose messages?

Answer (score 4):

I cannot imagine a scenario in which you would lose a message to be honest. BizTalk is exceptionally good at keeping state transactionally and will not lose messages out of the ordinary...

I think you would need to specify exactly how your orchestration is setup. A sequential convoy for example might potentially create a zombie message, but then you need to use that specific design pattern.

To answer how BizTalk restarts in case of an orchestration: when you restart a host instance, the host will dehydrate your (read: any) instance at the following persistence point or at the latest persistence point. At that time the host will restart and after restarting hydrate the instance back from the message box.

Comment: Thanks Pieter. I just asked as i got confusion regarding host instance. I heard from someone taht if message is in active mode.. means at memory and we try to restart host instance may causes loosing of message. But when i tried with sample application ... it is dehyderating message.

Comment: Exactly, imagine BizTalk having an active instance of an orchestration. When BizTalk starts the orchestration, there is a persistence point (save in msgbox db).

After that, BizTalk has a hardware failure, so whenever the instance is active again, the orchestration will resume from the last persistence point.

Glad I could help